# Follow-Up to "Prepending _Variable_ Folder Names to a List of Files"

Tags: bash, scripting

I received several good answers to my original question, and have opted to use the bash solution offered by @Giles Quenot, which was

```
#!/bin/bash

str=$(<file)

for i in $str; do
    if [[ $i =~ ^[A-F][A-Z][0-1] ]]; then
        echo "${i:0:2}/$i.jpg"
    fi
done
```

which converts a text file containing

```
AF002
AI003
AA001
AD005
AD006
AI002
```

into

```
AF/AF002.jpg
AI/AI003.jpg
AA/AA001.jpg
AD/AD005.jpg
AD/AD006.jpg
AI/AI002.jpg
```

However, I created a bash script entitled `AddPath.sh` and have two totally newbie-related problems:

1. I have been unable to adapt the above commands to operate on a file in the "1" position after the script name; i.e. I want to write `AddPath.sh TrialList.txt > TargetFile.txt` since I will have to use this script possibly scores of times, each acting on a different file.  Please help me overcome my ignorance.
2. It turned out that most of the files I will have to create file paths for will be on SanDisk thumb drives, which generically are called `NO NAME`.  No sweat, I thought.  I will just add modify the echo line in the recommended script to 
   `echo "NO NAME/${i:0:2}/$i.jpg"`.  That seemed to work for the first try, but on subsequent runs it inserts an extra carriage return (maybe linefeed?) so that I get the output on my iMac:

   ```
   NO NAME/AF/AF002
   .jpg
   NO NAME/AI/AI003
   .jpg
   NO NAME/AA/AA001
   .jpg
   NO NAME/AD/AD005
   .jpg
   NO NAME/AD/AD006
   .jpg
   NO NAME/AI/AI002
   .jpg
   ```

Again, most likely complete newbie stupidity.  Please help.

Comment: Point 1 should be fairly easy: replace `file` by `$1` in your script.

Comment: Thank you, Kusalananda and AdminBee.  That solves problem #1.  I was short one $ sign.  I'm obviously still unclear about the difference between a variable and its value, but this helps me learn.

Answer (score 0):

Woohoo!  I actually solved a problem on my own!

The problem (2) is that the $i variable, for some reason, is including the carriage return at the end of the line of the original list.  It is unclear why the script is doing this now when it didn't before, but so be it.  I solved the problem by replacing
`echo "NO NAME/${i:0:2}/$i.jpg"` by `echo "NO NAME/${i:0:2}/${i:0:5}.jpg"`.  That precludes the copying of the carriage return at the end of the line.